# The fireworks PNG format, any insight? Any libs?

Tags: image-processing, png, fireworks

The ultimate goal is to export the pages in a fireworks png file to individual images. So I have a couple questions:

1. Do you know of anything -- library, application -- that does this already?
2. Do you have any information on the format? They store their information in specialized chunks, I assume. I'm just hoping the format of those chunks' payload is not so difficult to figure out.

I have not dug into any fireworks files yet. I am finding no information on the format, so that is next step, but I figured someone may know a bit and save me some time :).

What I hope (and probably isnt the case) is that each page is stored as PNG in separate IDAT chunks. Unlikely, though, due to the vector capabilities. Maybe they store svg format in the chunks?

Any help or discussion is appreciated. I plan to dig into this in the next couple days.

Ben

EDIT: Here are a couple things: the linked superuser post below indicates the files are APNG. fireworks files are not APNG. APNG contains animation chunks: acTL, fcTL, fdAT. Fireworks has, in addition to the IDAT chunks, prVW, mkBF, mkTS, mkBS, mkBT chunks but none of the APNG chunks.

There is a pretty solid post here on fireworks PNGs: http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=20592#p86243

So I suppose I need to know what these chunks do, and how to parse them.

Comment: might be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/50044/how-to-read-fireworks-png-multilayer-files-without-fireworks

Comment: Thanks. I saw that earlier and meant to reference it in this question. I don't think it is a straight up APNG format as fireworks doesn't know what to do with a proper APNG. Each frame isn't even shown in my copy of CS3...

Comment: prVW chunk is the 'Thumbnail Preview Chunk' http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/135/tn_13565.html I can find 0 information on the other four.

Answer (score 4):

Some digging I did on my own for the private chunk types in Adobe Fireworks files is as follows (assume Python slicing notation):

**prVW ("thumbnail preview?")**

```
Data format:
- bytes[0:4]   - Chunk length
- bytes[4:8]   - Chunk type
- bytes[8:10]  - zlib file magic 0x789c
- bytes[10:-8] - zlib data
- bytes[-8:-4] - zlib checksum
- bytes[-4:]   - Chunk checksum

After decompressing, the first 4-bytes are the value "0xcafebeef",
likely another file magic byte value for whatever format the data is
in.
```

**mkBF**

```
Data format:
- bytes[0:4]   - Chunk length
- bytes[4:8]   - Chunk type
- bytes[8:12]  - 0xfadecafe (file magic?)
- bytes[12:16] - big-endian length value?
- bytes[16:80] - 64-byte NULL-padded data field
- bytes[80:84] - Chunk checksum
```

**mkBS**

```
Data format:
- bytes[0:4]   - Chunk length
- bytes[4:8]   - Chunk type
- bytes[8:10]  - zlib file magic 0x789c
- bytes[10:-8] - zlib data
- bytes[-8:-4] - zlib checksum
- bytes[-4:]   - Chunk checksum
```

**mkBT**

```
Data format:
- bytes[0:4]   - Chunk length
- bytes[4:8]   - Chunk type
- bytes[8:12]  - 0xfacecafe (file magic?)
- bytes[12:16] - Unknown big-endian value.  Increments for
                 each mkBT chunk present, and appears to only
                 consume the lower 24-bits.
- bytes[16:84] - 68-byte NULL-padded data field
- bytes[84:86] - zlib file magic 0x789c
- bytes[86:-8] - zlib data
- bytes[-8:-4] - zlib checksum
- bytes[-4:]   - Chunk checksum

This chunk may contain a split/spanned zlib stream, as the decompressed
data is cut at 64kb per mkBT chunk and does not appear to carry a zlib
checksum value.  Decompressing each zlib stream and then concatenating them
all together does not appear to be wrong.
```

**mkTS**

```
Data format:
- bytes[0:4]   - Chunk length
- bytes[4:8]   - Chunk type
- bytes[8:10]  - zlib file magic 0x789c
- bytes[10:-8] - zlib data
- bytes[-8:-4] - zlib checksum
- bytes[-4:]   - Chunk checksum
```

Comment: this helped get me started on my own analysis of the Fireworks chunks. To add to it somewhat: the `mkBT`s each contain an independent padded 128x128 ARGB tile in their compressed data (which seem (?) to be cached bitmaps for faster rendering, not actual source-of-truth content). Larger areas are divided into multiple tiles. The `mkBS` and `mkTS` chunks both contain mostly-ASCII-format data denoting a node hierarchy (each node has a 3-character name followed by a 1-character data format `v`/`i`/`f`/`b`/`s`, then its data or child nodes inside `{}`). From here, it's a remarkably readable format!

Comment: The data formats are `v`: vector (contains other nodes); `i`: integer (contains an int in base-16 encoded as ASCII), `f`: float (contains a float in base-10 encoded as ASCII), `b`: boolean (`0` or `1` in ASCII), and `s`: string (contains a big-endian 16-bit length value, counting characters not bytes, followed by a big-endian UTF16 string)

Comment: `prVW` contains a 2-byte width and height of the preview image after its magic number, then a palette (which always ends with black - seems to be the only way to detect how long it is) followed by some data that I haven't figured out yet, then it _ends_ with the image data (1-byte indices into the palette), padded to a size of 128x128. Interestingly the padding around the preview image seems to be uninitialised memory, containing seemingly random structures (presumably whatever happened to be in that bit of memory before the image was saved)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Don't how much it helps, if you're trying to write an utility that gets a Fireworks PNG(APNG) and saves the pages, but here goes:

You could use the Export menu in Fireworks: **File > Export > Pages to Files**.

Also you could use the **Save as** option and choose **Photoshop PSD**.
This option preserves the pages as folders/groups int the Photoshop Layers Panel,
but it does rasterize vector shapes. Still, it could be handy if you want to [parse
a PSD](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/588226) instead of a APNG(to access images,pages).

I've put together a small script (mostly using the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Fireworks/10.0_Extending/WSF995BEA2-2FD0-477c-919C-C0754CB5ACA8.html)) which saves a PSD of your currently open Fireworks PNG to a folder you choose:

```
var doc = fw.getDocumentDOM();
var loc = fw.browseForFolderURL("select a folder to save pages");

var prevWarn = fw.getPref("PsdExport_Warn100"); // bool 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Warn100", false);    // don't warn. 

var kObjToLayer = 1; 
var kFlatten = 2; 
var prevLayers = fw.getPref("PsdExport_Layers"); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Layers", kObjToLayer);    // flatten layers or not. 

var kEffectEditable = 1; 
var kEffectRender = 2; 
var prevEffects = fw.getPref("PsdExport_Effects"); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Effects", kEffectEditable); 

var kTextEditable = 1; 
var kTextRender = 2; 
var prevText = fw.getPref("PsdExport_Text"); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Text", kTextRender); 

if(loc) fw.exportPSD(doc, loc+"/yourPages.psd"); 

// Put the prefs back. 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Warn100", prevWarn); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Layers", prevLayers); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Effects", prevEffects); 
fw.setPref("PsdExport_Text", prevText);
```

If you save this as a .jsf file, and have a document open in Fireworks, you should be able to just double click the .jsf file.

Also, noticed there's an [Export PSD extension](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1327518) available, which has more options than my little script here.

If you need the vector shapes, you can use **File Export > FXG and Images** and choose **All Pages** bellow the format. FXG is an xml format, and the [specs](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/FXG+2.0+Specification) are available.

HTH

Comment: I'd rather not have to rely on any adobe products or any GUI steps. I'd like to really automate the generation of these page exports.

Comment: Also, Fireworks files are unfortunately not APNG. They do not contain any of the APNG chunks; they contain proprietary 'private' chunks: prVW, mkBF, mkTS, mkBS, mkBT. It would be nice if they stored each page in a different APNG frame or something, but it is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: @BenO I think I understand, you're interested in building a tool that wool work on other machines(even a server) and get the conversion done regardless of any Adobe tools. Unfortunately, that's all I could help with. Hopefully you can get some assistance on the Fireworks forums or product blog.

Comment: It turns out fireworks has an RPC API which looks to be the lowest effort solution. It (CS5) even has a function called fw.exportPages() which exports all the pages to PNG. So i'll just need a running instance of fireworks and I can write a little front end for converting fireworks PNGs into normal PNGs. Fireworks XML RPC: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d1183c949219-7fff.html