# Open Fireworks PNG on Linux

Tags: linux, png, fireworks

Adobe Fireworks uses a multi-image PNG format that looks like APNG, but unfortunately is some weird proprietary format.

I work on Linux (Xubuntu), so I can't install Fireworks. I need a way to open such files and at least be able to extract them as regular PNG files, while keeping the layers. I found some Linux tools for APNG (obviously they don't work) but none for the Fireworks PNG format.

I know I can run Windows in a VM and install Fireworks, but it's overkill. I will only do this as a last resort.

Any ideas ?

EDIT : the image below is a Fireworks PNG. Your browser will most likely treat it as a regular PNG and display only picture 1 flatened (hand-drawn curvy stuff on a white background). If you download it and open it with Fireworks, you can see it actually contains 2 pictures, with two layers each.

[image: PNG example]

Comment: How about sharing such an image so we can try to read it?

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fireworks PNG format, any insight? Any libs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242402/the-fireworks-png-format-any-insight-any-libs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe get `wine` and install and run Fireworks using that. If you're having trouble, I found a nice tutorial [here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/105271/how-to-run-windows-software-on-ubuntu-with-wine/)

Comment: That would be a good compromise between the simple solution I pray for and the extreme VM / dual boot option. I'll accept that as an answer if nothing more convenient shows up.

Comment: According to the [wine database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=665), Fireworks above CS4 should work splendidly.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Unfortunately what you want does not seem to exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242402/the-fireworks-png-format-any-insight-any-libs?rq=1)

From Adobe the very first link when you Google [*"fireworks to png"*](https://www.adobe.com/support/fireworks/export/fw_export_vs_sav/fw_export_vs_sav02.html)

> Technically speaking, Macromedia chose PNG (which stands for Portable
> Network Graphics) as the native file format for Fireworks because the
> format has both open source and proprietary characteristics. In most
> applications, the default file format is proprietary, meaning other
> applications can't open it. PNG, however, is an open source file
> format. Some graphic applications and browsers can open PNGs too.
> **However, they can only read the graphical portion of a PNG's file information. Fireworks PNG files contain a second "chunk" of data that
> other applications can't read, which contains proprietary information
> about things like slicing, interactivity, and any Live Effects that
> may have been applied.**

The best you are going to do is the RPC interface mentioned in that link because the chunks that you are look like undocumented proprietary binary formats that will be extremely hard to reverse engineer to me when I look at your example image in a hex editor.

Comment: I know very little about file format rights. Is there a legal reason why a free software like GIMP would be allowed to open PSD (which is also proprietary and owned by Adobe) but not this format ?

Comment: has nothing to do with *rights* they have never published how to parse that block and the quoted statement implies they never will. **The moral of the story is do not use software that uses unpublished closed format data files and you will never be hostage to that software/company.**